# Find Roots in Do loop

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Task: Finding roots in loop

```
t = List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fx[x_] := a*x^2 - 5
List[Do[Print[FindRoot[fx[k] == 1, {a, 1}]], {k, 0, 5}]]
```

Output: Currently the output is as follows:

```
 {a-> 6}
 {a-> 1.5}
```

and so forth

But I want to have the values of a in a List in order to perfom further tasks (Plotting root of f_a against a)

Comment: Using `Table` and `Map` are things you should get really comfortable with in general, so look them up in documentation center, and browse around here a bit: http://www.wolfram.com/support/learn/

Comment: Please [try to avoid procedural loops](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/193)

Comment: Don't use `Print` to generate values that you want to process further on. ssch has good advice. The `List` you use doesn't make sense here either. Another advice: Generally you should not define functions that have more dependencies than shown by the variables in the call pattern. In your case, the function depends on a as well, but that is not made explicit.

Answer (score 6):

You have many many options. Here are just two:

```
Table[FindRoot[fx[k] == 1, {a, 1}], {k, t}]
```

Or

```
FindRoot[fx[#] == 1, {a, 1}] & /@ t
```

---

Here is one way to make a plot of `t` vs the roots:

```
pts = Table[{k, a /. FindRoot[fx[k] == 1, {a, 1}]}, {k, t}];
ListLinePlot@pts
```

[image: Example plot of t vs roots]